# How to turn off the auto conceal function in vim latex?

Tags: vim, latex

I have already set the concealleavel to 0, but the editor still help me conceal the formulas. For example,  $f=x$ will be shown as f=x and
\delta will be replace with a Greek letter.
Could you anyone help me fix the problem?
（Sorry I can't post an image... orz)

Answer (score 2):

Try `let g:tex_conceal = ''` Also read `:h tex_conceal`.

Comment: Thanks! It's  'indentline' that has overwrited the conceallevel.